PROVE: $\frac{1}{2}a^2-b^2\leq(a+b)^2.$
I don't know how to start this problem. I need to prove that for all $a, b\in\mathbb{R}$, that
$$\frac{1}{2}a^2-b^2\leq(a+b)^2.$$
I have access to the following inequality:
$$ab\leq\frac{a^2}{2t}+\frac{tb^2}{2}$$
for all $t>0$. I have tried several choices of $t$, including $t=1$, $t=1/2$, and $t=2$, but none seem to work. The main issue I am running into is that this inequality gives an upper bound on $ab$, when in reality I need a lower bound. Any suggestions?

You might profit from reading our guidelines for how to ask a good question, with special emphasis on how you can avoid I don't know how to start questions.

$\frac{1}{2}a^2-b^2\leq(a+b)^2\iff 0\le \frac 12a^2 + 2ab + 2b^2\iff 0 \le a^2+4ab + 4b^2 \iff 0\le (a+2b)^2$.

"The main issue I am running into is that this inequality gives an upper bound on ab, when in reality I need a lower bound." Then replace $a$ with $-a$. $\frac 12a^2-b^2\le (a+b)^2\iff -2ab \le \frac 12a^2 + 2b^2\iff -ab \le \frac 14a^2+b^2=\frac 1{2\times 2}(-a)^2+\frac {2b^2}2$.  So let $t=2$.

After expanding and removing denominators, your inequality is equivalent to
$$
a^2+4ab+4b^2\ge 0
$$
which is clearly true since the left hand side is a perfect square, namely $(a+2b)^2$.

We have that by $\frac b a =x-\frac12$
$$\frac{1}{2}a^2-b^2\leq (a+b)^2 \iff \left(x+\frac12\right)^2+\left(x-\frac12\right)^2- \frac12\ge0 \iff 2x^2\ge 0$$


"I have tried several choices of t, including t=1, t=1/2, and t=2, but none seem to work. The main issue I am running into is that this inequality gives an upper bound on ab, when in reality I need a lower bound. Any suggestions?"

I'm loath to encourage people to rely on formulas but your formula (which I haven't seen before)

$ab\leq\frac{a^2}{2t}+\frac{tb^2}{2}$

applies to all real numbers and as only squares are on the RHS we can replace the $a$ and $b$ with negatives and get
$(-a)b \le \frac {(-a)^2}{2t}+\frac {tb^2}2$.
Now just use $t=2$ and the whole thing works.
If we are going to use this formula frequently, I'd note that
$\pm ab \le \frac {a^2}{2t} + \frac {tb^2}2$
so another maybe stronger/more flexible way of putting it is
$0\le |ab| \le \frac {a^2}{2t} + \frac {tb^2}2$.
....
But I'd have personally just derived it from scratch myself as the other answers had.
$\frac{1}{2}a^2-b^2\leq(a+b)^2\iff $
$0 \le \frac 12a^2 + 2ab + 2b^2\iff $
$0 \le a^2 + 4ab + 4b^2 \iff $
$0 \le (a+2b)^2$
